# Using Awk or an alternative to insert a logical new line in a sequence

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have raw data that takes the form of 50 lines as below:

09-06-16 16:45:00 1100000000
09-06-16 17:00:00 1200000000
09-06-16 17:15:00 1300000000
09-06-16 17:30:00 1400000000
09-06-16 17:45:00 1500000000

I'd like to use a command or create a script which adds a new line to the end of this sequence. The single line of data should advance the time one 15 minute interval and I'd also like the number to increase by 100000000. However I intend on writing a crontab script which would mimic data creation. Therefore where appropriate the date should change. And when the value is 1500000000 I'd like it to go back to 1100000000.

I've already written the script which removes the first line of data (more on my level) so as to ensure there are always 50 data points.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the time localtime or GMT, do you need to account for DST shifts

Comment: Hi Stephane, I won't need to account for DST shifts, or indeed leap years for the purpose of the exercise I'm hoping to undertake.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `perl` here to do the whole thing:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -i -lne '
  print unless $. == 1; # remove first line
  if (eof) {
    ($t, $n) = /(.*) (.*)/;
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($t, "%y-%m-%d %T") + 60*15;
    $n += 1e8; $n = 11e8 if $n > 15e8;
     print $t->strftime("%y-%m-%d %T $n")
  }' your-file
```

`Time::Piece` was added in 5.10. For older versions, you can always use `POSIX::mktime` instead:

```
perl -MPOSIX -i -lne '
  print unless $. == 1; # remove first line
  if (eof) {
    ($y, $mo, $d, $h, $mi, $s , $n) = /(..)-(..)-(..) (..):(..):(..) (.*)/;
    $t = mktime($s, $mi, $h, $d, $mo-1, $y+100) + 60*15;
    $n += 1e8; $n = 11e8 if $n > 15e8;
    print strftime("%y-%m-%d %T $n", localtime $t)
  }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Stephane,

I have no experience with perl but I'll take this and see if it works.

Comment: Not working for me,
I get the following:

String found where operator expected at data_sim.pl line 8, near "}'"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 1)
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at data_sim.pl line 8, near "}' dataonly"
        (Missing operator before dataonly?)
syntax error at data_sim.pl line 8, near "}'"

Again it is very possible that it's my ignorance, dataonly is the input file
Could I adjust only the last line, having copied it into a new text file, before using cat to attach it to the original

Comment: @Sneakers That's shell (`sh`) code invoking the `perl` interpreter, it's not the text of a `perl` script. That last argument passed to `perl` (above `your-file`) is the path to the file you want to modify

Comment: thanks again for your help. Unfortunately I'm using perl 5.8.4 on the Solaris system at work and can't seem to update it (No Time:Piece). I'll just keep plugging away with awk

Comment: @Sneakers, yes Time::Piece was added in 5.10 (released in 2007). I'll add a variant with POSIX::mktime which should work on ancient systems as well.